# Unity NavMeshAgent как задать движущуюся цель?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Юнит должен всегда двигаться к одной цели, которая движется.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class BanditMechanic : MonoBehaviour {
    NavMeshAgent agent;

    public Transform target;
    void Start() {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        agent.autoRepath = true;
        agent.SetDestination(target.position);
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
 //       agent.destination = target.position;
    }
}
```

Я написал такой код. Но юнит движется дергано(рывками), мне кажется это из-за того что я постоянно изменяю путь(Если задать статичную цель он движется нормально). Как правильно задавать цель, которая постоянно перемещается?

Answer (score 0):

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    _navMeshAgent.SetDestination(_player.position);
}
```

Все работает нормально. Ничего не дергается. Наверное, дело в другом.